# How to print full pyramid?

Tags: python, indentation

I want to print a full pyramid.

Below is the code:

```
num = int(input('enter the No of Rows '))

for i in range(0,num):
     for j in range(0,m-i-1):
            print(' ',end="") 
    for k in range(0,(2*i+1)):
            print('*',end="")   
    print()
```

But during compilation it shows error:

```
File "<tokenize>", line 6
    for k in range(0,(2*i+1)):
    ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Can Someone please correct me regarding this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python makes use of indents (tabs or spaces) instead of brackets({ }) to determine the scope of a function so indentation is crucial for your code to function correctly. Double check to see if you indented correctly or to see if you mixed any spaces in with your tabs.

PS, you can use the Code Sample button (the one that looks like **{}**) when inserting code to make your code snippet more readable (which is very important considering it's Python)